# onitemclicklistener not working in custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android, I've made a listview to view songs from memory the listview is displaying all the songs and scrolling fine but the onclickitemlistener is not working, I saw all the answers related to this topic on the site but I couldn't solve it.
Any help will be appreciated

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
private boolean scannedSongs;
public ArrayList<Song> musiclist=null;
private boolean scanningSongs;
ListView listView;
MainActivity.customeadapter cus = new MainActivity.customeadapter();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    // imp permission request
  while (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
  {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
  }

  MMB.initialize(getBaseContext());

    if(!MMB.songs.isInitialized())
    {
        scanSongs(false);
    }




}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}




class customeadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return musiclist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout,null);
        ImageView Custom_imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Custom_imageView);
        TextView custom_songname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_songname);
        TextView custom_artistname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_artistname);
        Uri thumbnailuri=Uri.parse(musiclist.get(position).getFilePath());
        Custom_imageView.setImageURI(thumbnailuri);
        custom_songname.setText(((Song)musiclist.get(position)).getTitle());
        custom_artistname.setText(((Song)musiclist.get(position)).getArtist());
        return convertView;
    }
}

void scanSongs(boolean forceScan) {

    // Loading all the songs from the device on a different thread.
    // We'll only actually do it if they weren't loaded already
    //
    // See the implementation right at the end of this class.
    if ((forceScan) || (! MMB.songs.isInitialized())) {

      SingleToast.show(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.menu_main_scanning), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        new ScanSongs().execute();
    }
}

class ScanSongs extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    /**
     * The action we'll do in the background.
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            // Will scan all songs on the device
            MMB.songs.scanSongs(MainActivity.this, "external");
            return MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.menu_main_scanning_ok);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.menu_main_scanning_not_ok);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called once the background processing is done.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        musiclist=MMB.songs.getSongs();
     SingleToast.show(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        listView.setAdapter(cus);
    }
}}
```

activity layout XML

```
tools:context="com.example.sreyash.musicplayer.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="380dp"
    android:layout_height="468dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/seguisym"
    android:text="Songs"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/segeo"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.016" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:background="@drawable/swipe"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.952"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sidebar"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.048"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />
```

custom layout for listview items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Custom_imageView"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Custom_songname"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/album_art" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/custom_songname"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:fontFamily="@font/comicsansms"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/segeo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_artistname"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/custom_songname"
    android:layout_below="@+id/custom_songname"
    android:fontFamily="@font/seguisym"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/segeo"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:typeface="normal" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/custome_sharebutton"
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/custom_songname"
    android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/share"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
     />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove `android:clickable="false"
 android:focusable="false"`  this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.. its working fine to me:

1.In your CustomAdapter Class inside getView() method ,put this following code.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx,"Position :"+position+" clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

I hope this too help you.Let me know if it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

make an interface to handle click event into custom adapter like below ..

```
  onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;

public void setOnItemClickListner(CommentsAdapter.onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
}

public interface onItemClickListner {
    void onClick(String str);//pass your object types.
}
```

and In adapter in GetView() method add this below line to click event ..

```
        // outerContiner is view object
    outerContiner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListner.onClick(data.get(position).itemName);
        }
    });
```

then after in activity after adapter bind into list view call below code ..

```
 adapter.setOnItemClickListner(new CommentsAdapter.onItemClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(String str) {
            Log.d("Value of Click",str);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
llistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,long arg3) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
   });
```

Instead of

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```